# HTML / Javascript - Relate a textarea's height to another's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

```
<textarea style="resize: vertical; height: 200px;"></textarea>
<textarea style="resize: vertical; height: 200px;"></textarea>
```

The above code creates 2 textareas positioned side to side. Just in case, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m4d9G/1/) is a fiddle.

I want to make it such that if either of the textareas are resized, the other textarea will be resized (relative to the height of the other textarea). So how do I accomplish that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize event for textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea)

Comment: ok and I really want to eat some Cheerios but I'm to lazy to go to the superMarket

Comment: @PaulRad-Dupuy It may not be, Im not sure how to change the height of the textarea relative to the other textarea

Comment: You can take help of this link http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/Z7HDn/67/

Comment: This topic should help if you want to do it with pure JS:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937721/how-to-detect-textarea-size-change-with-pure-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be Help You

Your HTML

```
<textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
<textarea id="txt2"></textarea>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#txt1").resizable({
    resize: function() {
        $("#txt2").width($(this).width());
        $("#txt2").height($(this).height());


    }
});
```

You can also refer [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/butani_vijay010/HhSYG/409/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing around with the [onresize Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp)

**Definition and Usage**

The onresize event occurs when the size of an element has changed.

**Syntax:**

*In HTML:*

```
<element onresize="SomeJavaScriptCode">
```

*In JavaScript:*

```
window.onresize=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

Hope you can figure it out.